# mysql slow speed simple query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a very simple sql query which is just a `select * from "table name"`
I have not indexed my table or anything else special.

The problem is that when I execute it through `phpmyadmin`, the query takes about 0.003 seconds but when I execute it through a browser in my web site it takes about 3 minutes!

There are 20K rows in the table and 19 fields. Can anyone help me?

```
include "config.php"; //Connect to Database

$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
$num_rsl=mysql_num_rows($query);
echo '<table border="1">';
    for($i=0; $i <$num_rsl; $i++)
{
echo '<tr>';
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['idLeistung'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtEAN'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtReifenBreite'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtReifenQuerschnitt'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtReifenBauart'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtReifentragfahigkeit'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtReifenGeschwindigkeitsindex'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtReifenTTTL'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtReifenProfil'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtHersteller'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtbestand'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['FZG'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtEinsatzZweck'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtArtikelNr'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtBeschreibung'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtArtikelNrA2'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['dtFremdVKPreis'].'</td>'; 
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: And that's why you don't use `mysql_*` anymore.

Comment: the displayed source has nothing to do with the described problem.

Comment: there is no select * from "table name" !

Comment: ok, after the update: i would assume the 3 minutes are used to actually render the 20k rows, not querying for it

Comment: i updated the content...i made a mistake with the code...sorry...what do you mean there is no selectselect * from "table name"
the problem is not with the code execution but with the speed

Comment: Your application will not scale. May be you find a way to reduce the time, but the table will increase and you will run into the same problems, soon. Think about your application and a concept where you do not need to fetch all rows.

Comment: I agree with scones. What are you doing to actually measure the time it takes to execute the query? Make sure you're doing it only server-side to eliminate the time it takes to download and render by the browser.

Comment: don't display 19k results in the browser, for that reason, people use pagination

Comment: That's a whole boatload of separate string concatenation operators and "echo" instructions. Is there a reason the whole table row is not being (more efficiently) output using e.g. `printf("<td>%s</td><td>%s</td>...",arg,arg,...);`.  I don't really think that's the problem though... I think the issue may be the time it takes the web browser to parse through all the HTML and to render a page.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, phpmyadmin modifies queries you issue through it to MySQL to limit the number of rows in the result set.  Your

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

most likely gets changed by phpmyadmin to

```
SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 0, 30
```

Pulling thirty rows certainly takes less time than pulling all the rows.

@scones mentioned this in the comments: pulling 20K rows from a table, turning them into a big old HTML table, and sending them over the wire to your browser takes a lot of elapsed time.  But that elapsed time is probably mostly determined by the performance of your web server (where PHP runs) and the wire between server and browser.

Comment: so there is no reason to do something more expect pagination?i ask because i dont know the use of index...